# SQL: merge 3 rows into 1

Tags: sql, select, join

There is a table in which every 3 rows together represents a meaningful object as belows:

```
id  colA   key   ...
ida value1 keyA  ...
ida value2 keyB  ...
ida value3 keyC  ...
idb value4 keyA  ...
idb value5 keyB  ...
idb value6 keyC  ...
```

It should be converged as follows(colA to keyA, colB to keyB, colC to keyC):

```
id  colA   colB   colC   ...
ida value1 value2 value3 ...
idb value4 value5 value6 ...
```

Totally no idea how to compose the right SQL. It might be two LEFT JOINs, but can't get it done. Please help.

Comment: here the SQL can be tested http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: is there a way irrelevant to RDBMS? if not, Oracle can be assumed.

Comment: Refer https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: I think the blog is not the same question as mine. my table has **3*n** rows which should be converged into **n** rows. Is that possible to PIVOT them?

Comment: Yeh, it's important. In mysql, it's group_concat, but in Oracle you'd need wmsys.wm_concat or even something else (with Oracle it's version-dependent... ugh). Each db will have its own meth, not part of ANSI SQL at all as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that (this is a SQL Server syntax):

```
select distinct id, 
   (select top 1 colA from table1 t
    where t.[key] = 'keyA' and t.id = table1.id) as colA,
   (select top 1 colA from table1 t
    where t.[key] = 'keyB' and t.id = table1.id) as colB,
   (select top 1 colA from table1 t
    where t.[key] = 'keyC' and t.id = table1.id) as colC
from table1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4370/7)